# swift - save plist dictionary without overwriting keys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am creating a note app, i am trying to save the data to a plist dictionary however, with the code I have when I save a new note is going to replace the old one.

How could add the new data in the dictionary without replacing the old one?

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
            let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
            let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
            var dict: NSMutableDictionary = ["XInitializerItem": "DoNotEverChangeMe"]
            //saving

            dict.setObject(noteResult.text, forKey: nameSave.text)

            //writing

            dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            println("Saved note.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
```

Loading notes:

```
func loadNotes(){

        let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let DocumentsDirectory = plistPath[0] as! String
        let path = DocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

            if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes", ofType: "plist") {

                let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
                println("Bundle notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
                fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
                println("copy")

            } else {
                println("notes.plist not found")
            }


        }else {
            println("note.plist already exists")

            //fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
        }

        let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        println("Loaded notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
        var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

        if let dict = myDict {
            //load values

        } else {

            println("worning ccould not create dictionary from notes.plist, default values will be used")
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1:** Could you please put a break point and double check after loading dictionary from file system, it contains the data that was saved previously. This most likely be true and then point 2 would help you. If this point is breaking then please ensure to fix this and you will crack it :).

**Point 2:** Dictionaries are bound to have unique keys. Problem is in your below statement. Make sure every time you save new note, it gets saved with new key. Put a check on 
nameSave.text value whenever you are saving data in dictionary.

```
dict[nameSave.text] = noteResult.text
```

**EDIT:**

I see the issue here is you are not initializing your dictionary with already saved file in file system. You must first ensure that you are populating your dictionary with **notes.plist** in file system and then append new data to it and finally save it back.

This is how I would do this; just combined both of your mentioned methods in a flow. Call this function on trigger of Save operation. Here, I think, first time check might be missing. I did not test this code so please bear with me.

```
func saveNotes() {
    // First fetch old notes
    let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let DocumentsDirectory = plistPath[0] as! String
    let path = DocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

        if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes", ofType: "plist") {

            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
            println("Bundle notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
            println("copy")

        } else {
            println("notes.plist not found")
        }


    } else {
        println("note.plist already exists")

        //fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
    }

    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    println("Loaded notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
    var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

    if let dict = myDict {
        // Save new value
        dict.setObject(noteResult.text, forKey: nameSave.text)
    } else {
        println("worning ccould not create dictionary from notes.plist, default values will be used")
    }

    // Now save it back
    dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)

}
```

Comment: thank you, the key is alway saved with a different value. nameSave.text is a UITextField where the user choses a value for the key to be saved

Comment: @SNos Please see my updated post. Please ensure to populate your already saved data in your dictionary before proceeding with new data appending.

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav, I get that I need to load the old value and append the new one before saving it. But i cannot figure out how to solve this. Please see my update post with my loading function

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please check it out. @SNos

Comment: NSDictionary does not have a member maned 'setObject' & Use of unresolved identifier 'dict'

Comment: I m assuming you are declaring your dictionary as var. Please check my update on this line.

Comment: I have changed var with let however, it is still giving me the same errors.. Please see picture attached

Comment: I don't think you took a look at my update. I want you to change the syntax to `dict[nameSave.text] = noteResult.text`.

Answer (score 0):

For Future reference the solution was:

```
// First fetch old notes
            let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
            let DocumentsDirectory = plistPath[0] as! String
            let path = DocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

            if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

                if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes", ofType: "plist") {

                    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
                    println("Bundle notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
                    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
                    println("copy")

                } else {
                    println("notes.plist not found")
                }


            } else {
                println("note.plist already exists")

                //fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
            }

            var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

            if let dict = myDict {
                // Save new value
                var noteResultAll = "Date: " + saveDate.text! + "\n" + noteResult.text

                dict.setValue(noteResultAll, forKey: nameSave.text)
                dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
            } else {
                println("worning ccould not create dictionary from notes.plist, default values will be used")
            }

            // Now save it back

            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            println("Loaded notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
```